# Dictionary and elif

Tags: python, random, dictionary

In the book "Python for the absolute beginner" by Michael Dawson, in the chapter on Lists and Dictionaries I have learned a great deal and am trying to make a new program as practice using the old Magic 8-Ball as my inspiration.  Below is the code I have come up with so far.

It works up to a point...the random generated number gets generated but the elif doesn't seem to work.  I know there are better ways and simpler ways, but I am doing this to reinforce my understanding of dictionaries.

I have put several print statements in to see if I was getting a number selected and the else statement is if all goes bad.  As the code stands now all I get is the number printed and the else produces "Does not compute.  Exit works fine. I have also confirmed the dictionary is fine using the commented out print "ball" statement.

So my issue is why does the elif statement seem to not process the random number generated.  Whom ever answers has my heartfelt thanks and appreciation.

```
# Import the modules
import sys
import random

 # define magic 8-ball dictionary
ball = {"1" : "It is certain.",
        "2" : "Outlook is good.",
        "3" : "You may rely on it.",
        "4" : "Ask again later.",
        "5" : "Concentrate and ask again.",
        "6" : "Reply is hazy, try again later.",
        "7" : "My reply is no.",
        "8" : "My sources say no"}
# for items in ball.items():
#              print(items)

ans = True

while ans:
    question = input("Ask the Magic 8 Ball a question: (press enter to quit) ")

    answer = random.randint(1,8) 
    print(answer)

    if question == "":
        sys.exit()

    elif answer in ball:
        response = ball[answer]
        print(answer, response)
    else:
        print("\nSorry", answer, "does not compute.\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking up on the dictionary with a number whereas the keys are strings in the dict. So, you have to convert the number to string with `str`.

Change

```
answer = random.randint(1,8)
```

to

```
answer = str(random.randint(1,8))
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much.  I now know where I was going wrong: mixing str and int.

Comment: Among the several great answers, yours was first and exactly what I needed.  I do appreciate all of the answers though from all those contributing.  What a great community Python is.

Answer (score 3):

`random.randint()` returns an integer. Your dictionary's keys are all strings. Thus, when you do `answer in ball`, it will **always** be `False`, because `"1" != 1`

What you can do is either make all the keys integers (remove the quotation marks), or make `answer` a string by doing:

```
answer = str(random.randint(1,8))
```

---

Note that you shouldn't be using an `elif` here. If your input is nothing, both your `if` and `elif` will be True, and most of the time you don't want this. Instead, change your `elif/else` to just an `if/else`:

```
if question == "":
    sys.exit()

if answer in ball:
    response = ball[answer]
    print(answer, response)
else:
    print("\nSorry", answer, "does not compute.\n")
```

One final thing. `answer` will always be in `ball`, because you dynamically created the dictionary. Here, you can use `dict.get()`. Eg:

```
if not question: # You can do this instead
    sys.exit()

print(ball.get(answer))
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Based on the comments have tried and succeeded using first str and then changed dict to number and it works great and now I fully understand my mistake and fix.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

The string `"1"` is not the int `1`. So `answer` is actually not in `ball`. 
Try converting it like `answer = str(random.randint(1,8))`